# why does the Previous content in GridView disappears after button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to make a web application using asp.net. I am taking some data from database and binding it to a GridView on a button click event. Here is the source file :

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Order.aspx.cs" Inherits="Order" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style2 {
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <table class="auto-style2">
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_Name" runat="server" Text="Name"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td rowspan="4">
                <asp:GridView ID="GridViewCart" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="100%" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
                    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FDF5AC" />
                    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4D0000" />
                    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FCF6C0" />
                    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#820000" />
                </asp:GridView>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_Contact" runat="server" Text="Contact"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Contact" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_Item" runat="server" Text="Item"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_select_item" runat="server">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_Quantity" runat="server" Text="Quantity"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Quantity" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btn_AddCart" runat="server" OnClick="btn_AddCart_Click"  Text="Add To Cart" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btn_PlaceOrder" runat="server" Text="Place Order" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
</asp:Content>
```

And here is the code behind file :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Order : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    //Order obj = new Order();
    static int i = 0;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ddl_select_item.DataSource = MenuServices.ShowMenu();
            ddl_select_item.DataTextField = "itemName";
            ddl_select_item.DataValueField = "itemId";
            ddl_select_item.DataBind();

        }

    }
    protected void btn_AddCart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int tempindex = int.Parse(ddl_select_item.SelectedItem.Value);

        SqlConnection con;
        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlDataReader dr;
        con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from Menu where itemId = @id";
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("id", tempindex);
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        //int tempflag = 0;
        if (dr.Read())
        {


                OrderMenu.orderCart[i] = new Item { itemId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["itemId"]), itemName = dr["itemName"].ToString(), itemPrepTime = dr["itemPrepTime"].ToString(), itemPrice = Convert.ToInt32(dr["itemPrice"]) };

        }


        showgrid(OrderMenu.orderCart);
    }
    public void showgrid(Item[] obj1)
    {
        GridViewCart.DataSource = obj1.ToList<Item>();
        GridViewCart.DataBind();


    }
}
```

My issue is every time I press the "Add to Cart" button the current selected data from drop down list is shown in the GridView and not the previous ones. I need the data to append in the GridView along with the previous ones.
[image: My first selection and "Add to cart" button click]

[image: My second selection from drop down and "Add to cart" button click]

Comment: Maybe related with *ViewState*? . https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx

Comment: I have set the EnableViewState to true in GridView.

Comment: In your `for` loop you are overwriting index `i` four times. What is it you actually are trying to do there?

Comment: I was trying something else. It was throwing null exception so i did it. Edited it.

Comment: Let me know if Item class and Order class are required.

Comment: I'm only surprised why you have `0`s in lines 2 through 4. Use `while(dr.Read()){...}` and remove your `for` loop. Also you didn't close connection after you finish reading. This doesn't change your current result but  may badly affect performance later.

Comment: @VishnuHariDadhich, another tip, don't use static variables unless your intent is to share them application wide.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev I think it is likely the query is returning a single row since it appears to select by an id, thus no `while`. I could be mistaken but let's not send OP scrambling on something that is not the problem.

Comment: Removed the for loop. And there is only one row in the data reader so while loop is not required i guess.

Comment: @Crowcoder thanks for the tip

Comment: @Crowcoder I expected the same data in all 4 lines ;). The code in OP is awful and the only way to improve it is to rewrite from scratch.

Comment: @VishnuHariDadhich I think you want to `Add` items to `OrderMenu.orderCart`, not set the item at index `i` each time.

Comment: Should I increment the static variable i everytym after the button click event ??

Comment: @VishnuHariDadhich I don't see a need for the variable at all. And since it is static anyone else using the site will change it out from under you anyway. You should just add items to the array or make it a List so you can literally use the `Add()` method. Of course, you haven't shown how you create and manage `OrderMenu`, is that also a static item?

Comment: Well it worked anyhow, i just incremented the variable `i` and my purpose is resolved. Thank you everyone.

Comment: @Crowcoder well i am learning somehow on my own. Making it a list is a better option i will opt.`OrderMenu` class contains a static property `OrderCart` which is an array .

Comment: @VishnuHariDadhich, ok, but this is only going to work while you have a single user on the site, just keep that in mind if you start experiencing strange behavior.

Comment: @Crowcoder Thanks a lot, i will keep it in mind. :)